# Why am i getting 404 Bad request when i hit my back end from Node server?

Tags: node.js

React is invoking a Node API and Node is interacting with back end micro-services. I am making a POST request where an Authorization token needs to be part of the headers and also know the user's name.

I have provided my code below and cannot find the reason why am i getting 400 - Bad request since i am not posting any file that can exceed server capacity. 
Really appreciate your help.

Here is how my request should be:

```
curl -d '{"userName": "Tom and Jerry"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer dwgqhsfjnfjjfldklkfldskglkylrkylktyl" -X POST http://nodejs-appfactory1:25002/appurl-service/api/appurl/getClientList
```

Here is my request in Node:

```
  app.post('/getData', async (req, res) => {
                var getToken = (authorization_token) => {
                    return prop.get(authorization_token);
                };

                var authorization_token = getToken('authorization_token');

                var post_data = querystring.stringify({
                    'userName': req.session.user
                });


                var options = {
                    host: 'nodejs-appfactory1',
                    port: 25002,
                    path: 'appurl-service/api/appurl/getClientList', // the rest of the url with parameters if needed
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': authorization_token
                    }
                };

                var post_req  = http.request(options, function (resp) {
                    var responseString = "";

                    resp.on("data", function (data) {
                        responseString += data;
                        console.log("Success ---- Response from server:" +responseString);
                        res.json(responseString);
                        // save all the data from response
                    });
                    resp.on("end", function () {
                        console.log("Error ---- Response from Server:" +responseString);
                        // print to console when response ends
                    });
                });

                post_req .write(post_data);
                post_req .end();

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

In the curl request, is it supposed to be just 'http://xyz:3002/api/get' or 'http://xyz:3002/api/getData'?

Comment: Yeah getData is the API that React layer invoked. Insides getData, i am creating a new HTTP post request where in i am getting Bad request - 400